# Android mail application(how to)

Tags: android, email, delegates

*Dear StackOverflowers, first of all i'm not exactly sure if this is a true question for stackoverflow community so please try to forward me to a true destination before down voting..*

I want to develop a domain based android mail application. For example, if a mail containing some words like "bla bla bla" received from a domain like xyz.com, i will try to push an alarm. I also want to be able to activate voice alarm even tough the phone is in silent(or vibration) mode..
Now my questions are:

**1. Is it possible to catch(get) mail delegate methods to activate some other functionality**

**2. Will Android let me activate the voice alarm in silent mode?**

Aditional note: my mail server will be Microsoft Exchange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to catch(get) mail delegate methods to activate some other functionality

Yes, to an extent. You can have your users sign into the mail app with their email accounts and receive the emails as they come. AFAIK, you cannot access incoming email unless your own app is the receiving one. So while you will be able to receive email if the user logs in with your app, you will not be able to read the ones in the Gmail app.

> Will Android let me activate the voice alarm in silent mode?

You can have your app adjust the volume to high if its on silent, play your notification sound, and then put it back on silent. This is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Thanks, i'm a nativa iOS developer, iOS has some restrictions so i couldn't be sure

Comment: @iblis I figured you had an iOS background from `delegate methods` in your question :P Nobody uses the word delegate on Android. But it can be done, and not too hard either

Comment: FOR YOUR EDIT: I will need just to read mails from my mail application, i have a bash script which creates a warning mail to our system desc group in company, all mails come from the same Exchange server and also the domain is like xyz.com as i have mentioned before.. If just i can get the notification of a new mail received, i think i will do everything well.. God bless [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) :)